# Track where PayPal transaction originated across multiple stores

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, e-commerce

I will be managing multiple ecommerce stores for clients.

The stores will be WordPress stores running WooCommerce. Each store will be on a separate subdomain. Each store will essentially be a clone and stock the same several items. Each store will have the same PayPal checkout running off a single, central PayPal account and as payments come in, I will disburse payments to the storeowners.

When orders come in, is there any way to track from which store a specific order came? I don't mind which form this takes, whether from the PayPal side or a cookie or a plugin or a script or anything along those lines, but I would obviously like to, and must, implement a solution where I am able to track the store or URL from which a specific PayPal transaction originated.

Would appreciate any thoughts or pointers on how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal keeps track of the Invoice ID you pass to them and actually checks upon payment if an order with that Invoice ID has already been paid. WooCommerce allows you to prefix the invoice ID, having a default prefix of WC- . WooCommerce would generate a PayPal invoice ID of WC– + ORDER_ID. As an example this would result in: WC-100. Normally this would be unique, because you can’t have 2 orders with the same ID in WooCommerce. But I have 3 WooCommerce shops, so there’s a chance that an order with the same ID was done at PayPal by one of my other shops. When this was the case PayPal would prevent the user from paying the order because a payment for the same invoice ID was already recorded.